# Rails simple_form : Adding value to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, simple-form

I have a modal with an array column which stores user ids. When a user clicks a specific button their id gets added to the array. However currently with the below code each time a new id is stored its just replacing the one that already exists. So its only ever storing 1 id.

```
= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :volunteers_ids, value: current_user.id, multiple: true
  =f.button :submit
```

Other related code:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:volunteers_ids => [])
end
```

Migration:

```
def change
  add_column :posts, :volunteers_id, :string, array: true, default: []
end
```